# Performance issue on a simple query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I have near ~10'000 records in the Image table and I want to retrieve them with a query.

The image model definition:

```
{
  "name": "Image",
  "plural": "Images",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": false
    },
    "uploaddate": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "shootingdate": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "imageStatusTitle": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "category": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "canton": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "rights": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "earmarked": {
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "imageStatus": {
      "type": "embedsOne",
      "model": "ImageStatus",
      "foreignKey": "",
      "options": {
        "persistent": false
      }
    },
    "categories": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "ImageCategory",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "votes": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "WebsiteUser",
      "foreignKey": "imageId",
      "through": "ImageVote"
    },
    "original": {
      "type": "embedsOne",
      "model": "File",
      "property": "original",
      "options": {
        "persistent": false
      }
    },
    "small": {
      "type": "embedsOne",
      "model": "File",
      "property": "small",
      "options": {
        "persistent": true
      }
    },
    "medium": {
      "type": "embedsOne",
      "model": "File",
      "property": "medium",
      "options": {
        "persistent": true
      }
    },
    "large": {
      "type": "embedsOne",
      "model": "File",
      "property": "large",
      "options": {
        "persistent": true
      }
    },
    "xlarge": {
      "type": "embedsOne",
      "model": "File",
      "property": "xlarge",
      "options": {
        "persistent": true
      }
    },
    "owner": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "WebsiteUser",
      "foreignKey": "fotographerId"
    },
    "widgets": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Widget",
      "through": "WidgetImage"
    }
  }
  ...
```

The query I will make is the following:

```
    const query = {
        fields: ['id', 'name', 'fotographerId'],
        include: {
            relation: 'owner',
            fields: ['id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'street', 'zip', 'city', 'email', 'phone', 'mobile', 'locale']
        }
    };

    if (0 < whereFilter.length) {
        query.where = {
            and: whereFilter
        };
    }

    app.models.Image.find(query, function(err, records) {
        ...
    }
```

The problem is that this query takes 5 minutes to execute. 
I then improve it by 4 minutes by removing the default ordering [explained in this issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/issues/55).

But anyways 4 minutes for such query on 10'000 document seems very slow to me. Do you see what can be the problem? Or do you have an idea how to speed up this query?

Comment: try making the fields You search on as index, this would improve your search

Comment: The where clause is empty here so actually there is no filter. Or you mean to make an index for the field I'm selecting?

Comment: i am suggesting you to make index on field You are selecting,

There is another issue that i thing You should improve, there are alot of subdocuments. you might want to revisit fields you need or you can reference..
the sub-documents we make become collection and each document has to search its relevant sub-document.
simple suggestion is, dont use so many sub documents.

Comment: I agree for the subdocuments. But still, here I'm including only the `owner` reference so is a simple lookup in another table. I think it will take 1s in a mysql table to do such a simple query. Anyways I will try to add a index for the selected fields. Thanks for the advice

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan Nothing change. It takes exactly the same time. As  expected, put an index on selected fields is actually not useful as there is no `where` filter here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone has the same problem. The cause of the performance issue was on a hook that execute some code every time a model was fetched/loaded. Now it takes 2 seconds to perform.